# JSch: Login to Destination Server from Jump Server. Jump server asks for passphrase for key which accepts an empty string

Tags: java, jsch

This is how it looks like when I attempt to connect to the destination server from the jump server.

[SSH Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x1kJ.png)

Firstly, it prompts me for the username and password of the jump server. 
Once logged in, I attempt to connect to the destination server. This is where that passphrase prompt comes in. All I need to do is hit enter when prompted for the passphrase and I will be prompted for the password.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    Session jumpServerSession = jsch.getSession(jumpServerHostUsername, jumpServerHostName, 22);
    jumpServerSession.setPassword(jumpServerPassword);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jumpServerSession.setConfig(config);
    jumpServerSession.connect();

    int assinged_port = jumpServerSession.setPortForwardingL(0, targetServerHostname, 22);
    System.out.println("portforwarding: "+
                           "localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+targetServerHostname+":"+22);
        //Main server connection session started
    Session targetServerSession =  jsch.getSession("root", targetServerHostname, 22);

    targetServerSession.setHostKeyAlias(targetServerHostname);

    targetServerSession.setPassword(targetServerPassword);
    targetServerSession.setIdentityRepository(null);

    java.util.Properties config1 = new java.util.Properties();
    config1.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    targetServerSession.setConfig(config1);
    targetServerSession.connect();
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHH5r.png)

As you can see from the console output above, the connection gets timed out which is unsurprising since I couldn't find a way to just send that empty passphrase. I googled quite a bit and found a few articles (using Robot and setting config to "PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password"). They didn't work for me. Finally, I am unable to download the key from the jump server as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Apologies. I don't have enough reputation to post the images.

Answer (score 1):

If the private key is not encrypted, there's nothing to be done in JSch. It will just use the key.

But I do not see you specifying your private key anywhere. If you expect the local JSch to somehow magically use the `.ssh/id_da` the key on the jump server, it won't. The JSch does not even know the jump server exists. You need the private key on the local machine and let JSch know about it.

Comment: That's the problem I am facing. I am unable to download the private key from the jump server. Is there a way I can specify jsch.addIdentity(path_to_key_on_jump_server)?

Comment: That does not make sense. Why are you not able to download the private from the the jump server?